# how to update table rows which contain comma separated values?

Tags: mysql

I have 2  tables 1st table contain names,email,vegetable_Fruits, and drinks

```
CREATE TABLE Likes
(
Name varchar(20),
email varchar(20),
Vegetables_Fruits varchar(20),
Drinks varchar(20)
)
```

i am storing name and email of people those like vegetable ,Fruits and drinks
A person can have any one value 
if a person likes vegetable i will update the table as

```
name email 1 0
```

if a person likes fruits then

```
name email 2 0
```

if a person likes drinks then

```
name email 0 1
```

Insert query

```
INSERT INTO Likes(Name,email,Vegetables_Fruits,Drinks)
     VALUES("aaa","aaa@example.com",1,0),("bbb","bbb@example.com",2,0),("ccc","cc@example.com",0,1),("ddd","dd@example.com",2,0),("eee","ee@example.com",2,0),("fff","ff@example.com",1,0),("ggg","gg@example.com",0,1),("hhh","hh@example.com",0,1)
```

I have another table which contain list of emails

```
CREATE TABLE emailList
(
Likes_Vegetables varchar(50),
Likes_Fruits varchar(50),
Drinks varchar(50)
)
```

Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO emailList(Likes_Vegetables,Likes_Fruits,Drinks)
       VALUES("aaa@example.com,ff@example.com","bbb@example.com,dd@example.com,'ee@example.com'","hh@example.com,gg@example.com,cc@example.com")
```

I want to update the 2nd table (emailList) based on the values of  1st table(Likes)
What is the query for this

Comment: A comma delimited list of emails is probably not a very good way to normalize data in a relational DB.

Comment: I am not did this my work is only updating this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update emailList 
set 
Likes_vegetables=(select Group_concat(email) from LIKES where Vegetables_Fruits=1),
Likes_Fruits=(select Group_concat(email) from LIKES where Vegetables_Fruits=2),
Drinks=(select Group_concat(email) from LIKES where Drinks=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were searching for `group_concat`,Maybe query like this

```
INSERT INTO emailList(Likes_Vegetables,Likes_Fruits,Drinks)
      values ( (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM Likes WHERE Vegetables_Fruits=1) , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM Likes WHERE Vegetables_Fruits=2) , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM Likes WHERE Vegetables_Fruits=0) )
```

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM Likes WHERE Vegetables_Fruits=2

Comment: i want to store this value in one temp variable

Comment: I just updated the answer with query see it will usefull for you or not @Athi

Answer (score -1):

This will solve your problem i guess--

> update emailList set Likes_Vegetables =
>   concat(Likes_Vegetables,"aaa@example.com"),
>                        Likes_Fruits = concat (Likes_Fruits, "ee@example.com"),
>                        Drinks = concat (Drinks, "cc@example.com");